# What exactly, is a "day"?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I have collected for myself several 'summons' and I'm very interested in trying them out. However, I'm hesitant to do so because they say they can only be used once per day. Well what defines a day? Is this a real-life day or a Southpark day? If it is the latter, then what makes up a Southpark day?

(I suppose I *could* save, use them and load the previous save, but that would defeat the purpose of asking this question.)

Comment: You could do the research yourself and ask anyway and answer your own question if you feel that the information could be useful for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A day is determined by completing certain amounts of the main story line.  Eventually in order to progress you'll need the abilities granted by what you get that following night, so it naturally weaves itself in.

Comment: Sometimes when I wander in the forest for a while, my parents come and take me home talking about how late it is. I then start back in my room. Does this count as a new day? Are story advancements the only way to go to the next day?

Comment: The one time I was "grounded" I just went outside and it was still day and nothing of consequence happened.

Comment: @Ender I just tested getting grounded by my parents  on a save file who has no more summons for the day and has already beaten the game. Even though they say 'go home and go to bed', after I re-spawned in my room I was unable to get a new summon item.